# Teradata sql Analytics - derived a new column for partitioned clause

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I have a Book table, and i want to derived a new column word1 as below:

Book:

```
+-------+------+------+-------+
| name  | page | line | word  |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 1    | The   |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 2    | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 3    | Time  |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 4    | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 2    | 1    | An    |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 2    | 2    | Tom   |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 2    | 3    | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 3    | 1    | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 3    | 2    | Jack  |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 3    | 3    | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 4    | 1    | Since |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 4    | 2    | They  |
+-------+------+------+-------+
| Book1 | 4    | 3    | Sam   |
+-------+------+------+-------+
```

Derived Word1 as
 CASE
 
        if any of the line for same page has 'The' then 'The'
        if any of the line for same page has 'An' then 'An'
        if any of the line for same page has 'A' then 'A'
        ELSE
 
        word at line 1

```
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| name  | page | line | word  | word1 |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 1    | The   | The   |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 2    | A     | The   |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 3    | Time  | The   |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 1    | 4    | A     | The   |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 2    | 1    | An    | An    |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 2    | 2    | Tom   | An    |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 2    | 3    | A     | An    |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 3    | 1    | A     | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 3    | 2    | Jack  | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 3    | 3    | A     | A     |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 4    | 1    | Since | Since |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 4    | 2    | They  | Since |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
| Book1 | 4    | 3    | Sam   | Since |
+-------+------+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply FIRST_VALUE and order by priority:

```
SELECT ...
   First_Value(word) 
   Over (PARTITION BY NAME, page
         ORDER BY 
            CASE word 
              WHEN 'The' THEN 1
              WHEN 'An'  THEN 2
              WHEN 'A'   THEN 3
              ELSE 99
            END, line)
FROM tab
```

Comment: This is a nice way to achieve the result. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a window functions and `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when word = 'The' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by page) > 0
             then 'The'
             when sum(case when word = 'An' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by book, page) > 0
             then 'An'
             when sum(case when word = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by book, page) > 0
             then 'A'
             else max(case when line = 1 then word end) over (partition by book, page)
        end) as derived_word            
from t;
```

Comment: instead of line=1, how can i change it for  if min(line) then word.

Comment: @D.Aquar . . . You would use `first_value()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions. `colaesce()` comes handy to simplify the logic here:

```
select 
    b.*,
    coalesce(
        max(case when word = 'The' then word end) over(partition by name, page),
        max(case when word = 'An'  then word end) over(partition by name, page),
        max(case when word = 'A'   then word end) over(partition by name, page),
        max(case when line = 1     then word end) over(partition by name, page)
    ) word1
from book b
```

Comment: This is not actually producing the right output, it assigns first matching   'The','An','A' to each line . I wanted to have all line (record) for same partitioning window to have either 'The' or 'An' or 'A' .

Comment: @D.Aquar: there was a typo in the window definition (`book` instead of `page`) - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wished to do this without `window functions`

```
select a.*, b.word1
from cte a
left join (select name, page ,coalesce(max(case word when 'the' then word end) 
                                      ,max(case word when'an' then word  end) 
                                      ,max(case word when 'a' then word end)
                                      ,max(case line when 1 then word end)) as word1
           from cte
           group by name, page) b on a.name=b.name and a.page=b.page;
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06d58c8fa813caa755b5cd24fa2c8923)**